# Background colouring of lines composed of repetitions of the comment character

Tags: colors

The following code changes the background colour of lines that are composed of the repetition of the comment character for `lisp-interaction-mode`.

```
(defface special-comment '((t (:background "orange"))))

(font-lock-add-keywords 'lisp-interaction-mode
   '(("^;;+$" 0 'special-comment t)))
```

I then transitioned the call to use `Syntax Classes` (`\s<` for  Comment Starter, `\s>` for Comment Ender).

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'lisp-interaction-mode
   '(("^\\s<\\s<\\s<+$" 0 'special-comment t)))
```

But, extending this even further, fails

```
(font-lock-add-keywords nil
   '(("^\\s<\\s<\\s<+$" 0 'special-comment t)))
```

What can be done to extend this for `prog-mode`?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Thank you, that is a better question. I don’t know the answer, but maybe if you read [chapter 36 Syntax Tables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Tables.html) of the Emacs Lisp Manual you will find it.

Comment: Would the related information be about Comment Starters  `<`  and Comment Enders  `>`  ?

Comment: Correct, but note the complications for languages with two–character starters and enders, like C with `/* comment */` or C++ with `// comment`.

Comment: For `C` and `C++` I want to use `^///+$` pattern.

Comment: Then you should probably build your regex from the first starter character followed by repetitions of the second starter character. That will cover `/**` as well.

Comment: I would like the first one repeated.

Comment: Well, then build your regex accordingly :)

Comment: But then get to the same problem, how to code it for all modes.  How does one use `Comment Starters <`  and  `Comment Enders >`  ?

Comment: This- did not work `(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("^\s<\s<\s<+$" 0 'special-comment t)))`

Comment: Good idea, I had forgotten about `\s`. But backslashes in regexes must be doubled up, because they are also inside of strings. Write them as `\\s<`.

Comment: It is still not correct `(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("^\\s<\\s<\\s<+$" 0 'special-comment t)))`

Comment: This does work `(font-lock-add-keywords 'lisp-interaction-mode  '(("^\\s<\\s<\\s<+$" 0 'special-comment t)))`.

Comment: But this does not work `(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("^\\s<\\s<\\s<+$" 0 'special-comment t)))`.

Comment: Voted to close based upon the overbroad question of:  "`How can this be adapted to take the comment character of *any mode*?`"  There are different methods used by font-lock to handle highlighting of comment, and that treatment varies depending upon the major-mode.  There is no universal answer as far as I am aware.  In addition, if a user wishes to attract heavy hitters such as Lindydancer, a tag of "colors" will not suffice.

Comment: @lawlist How about doing this for `prog-mode`?